# Runtime static middelware

Tags: express

Is it possible to generate path to static content in runtime? ex. at app start:

```
app.use('/static', express.static('base/image'))
```

and after some action I would like change it to

```
app.use('/static', express.static('users/user-name/image'))
```

and disable old one.

**[EDIT]**

I create my own middleware to handle this task.

```
app.use(/\/static\/.+/, (req, res, next) => {
        const path = req.originalUrl.replace('/api/static', applicationConfig.config.baseUploadPath)
            .replace(/%20/g, ' ');
        const file = fs.readFileSync(path);

        res.send(200, file);
        next();
    });
```

Comment: I don't think it can be done. General advice is to use parent directory if you want to achieve something like this.

Comment: Thanks for hint @RishikeshDhokare :) I create custom middleware for static files

Comment: You are welcome!